# pyspark dataframe not maintaining order after dropping a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create a dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a':range(12),'c':range(12)})).repartition(8)
```

its contents are :

```
df.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  3|  3|
|  5|  5|
|  6|  6|
|  8|  8|
|  9|  9|
| 10| 10|
|  2|  2|
|  4|  4|
|  7|  7|
| 11| 11|
+---+---+
```

But, If I drop a column, the remaining column gets permuted

```
df.drop('c').show()
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  0|
|  2|
|  3|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  9|
| 11|
|  1|
|  4|
|  8|
| 10|
+---+
```

Please help me understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to add my answer since I felt I could explain this slightly differently.

The repartition results in a `RoundRobinPartition`. It basically redistributes the data in round-robin fashion.

Since you are evaluating the dataframe again, it recomputes the partition after the drop.

You can see this by running a few commands in addition to what you have shown.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a':range(12),'c':range(12)})).repartition(8)

df.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
# +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#14L,c#15L]

print("Partitions structure: {}".format(df.rdd.glom().collect()))
# Partitions structure: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [Row(a=0, c=0), Row(a=1, c=1), Row(a=3, c=3), Row(a=5, c=5), Row(a=6, c=6), Row(a=8, c=8), Row(a=9, c=9), Row(a=10, c=10)], [Row(a=2, c=2), Row(a=4, c=4), Row(a=7, c=7), Row(a=11, c=11)]]

temp = df.drop("c")

temp.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
# +- *(1) Project [a#14L]
#   +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#14L,c#15L]


print("Partitions structure: {}".format(temp.rdd.glom().collect()))
# Partitions structure: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [Row(a=0), Row(a=2), Row(a=3), Row(a=5), Row(a=6), Row(a=7), Row(a=9), Row(a=11)], [Row(a=1), Row(a=4), Row(a=8), Row(a=10)]]
```

In the above code, the `explain()` shows the `RoundRobinPartitioning` taking place. The use of `glom` shows the redistribution of data across partitions.

In the original dataframe, the partitions are in the order that you see the results of `show()`.

In the second dataframe above, you can see that the data has shuffled across the last two partitions, resulting in it not being in the same order. This is because when re-evaluating the dataframe the repartition runs again.

##### Edits as per discussion in the comments

If you run a `df.drop('b')`, we are trying to drop a column that doesn't exist. So it's really what is called a `noop` or a no operation. So the partitioning doesn't change.

```py
df.drop('b').explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
# +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#70L,c#71L]
```

Similarly if you're adding a column and run it, the round partition runs before the column is added. This again results in the same partitioning and hence the order is consistent with the original dataframe.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('tt', f.rand()).explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [a#70L, c#71L, rand(-3030352041536166328) AS tt#76]
# +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
#    +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#70L,c#71L]
```

In the case of df.drop('c'), the column is first dropped and then the partitioner is applied. This results in a different partitioning since the resulting dataframe in the stage before the partitioning is run is different.

```py
df.drop('c').explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
# +- *(1) Project [a#70L]
#    +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#70L,c#71L]
```

As mentioned in another answer to this question, the round-robin partitioner is random for different data, but consistent with the same data on which the partition is run. So if the underlying data changes from the operation, the resulting partition will be different.

Comment: thank you for your valuable help :). I get your point that the action is computing the output from either the start or the last persist. Hence, the repartition is running again. But why is the repartition happening different in both cases? But, other intermediate steps like if I replace ```df.drop('b')``` with ```df.withColumn('tt', rand())``` doesn't seem to alter the order.  I am not able to understand why the partitioning is  changing depending upon that ```drop``` being there or not

Comment: The `df.drop('b')` is dropping a column that doesn't exist so the partitioning doesn't change. If you look at the explain plan of `df.withColumn...` it also doesn't really change the plan, the round robin partitioner is applied on the same set of columns. 
In the case of `df.drop('c')`, the column is first dropped and then the partitioner is applied. As someone else mentioned, round robin partitioning is random, but consistent for the same data it is partitioning. So if the data changes (an actual column that exists is dropped), you will not get the same partitioning as before.

Comment: That actually makes sense .. Thank you !! Mind adding this little bit to your answer? I will accept it then

Comment: Great! udpated @MiloMinderbinder